# How to insert punctuation marks in output string using format?

Tags: python, string, format

I need to parse text for lines containing specific keywords and print them out in this format (whitespaces are also important):

line 7, hit #1:
line 8, hit #2: 
....

When I try to insert ',' and '#' using {::=} and format, it prints out a mistake.

Here is my code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import sys

    if len(sys.argv) <= 2:
        print("Error", file=sys.stderr)

    filename = sys.argv[1]
    keyword = sys.argv[2]

    line_count = 0
    keyword_count = 0
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
         for l in f.readlines():
         line_count += 1
         if keyword in l:
            keyword_count += 1
            print ('{} {} {} {} {}'.format('line', line_count, 'hit', 
         keyword_count, l.rstrip()))
```

Comment: What does it print? What is the content of your file? What are the arguments passed to your program? Have you right indentation for your program?

Comment: `print ('{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}'.format('line', line_count, 'hit', 
         keyword_count, l.rstrip()))` ...?

Comment: It prints lines that contain keyword. The actual line is preceded by "line, line counter, hit, keyword counter". My program does what it should do. The only problem is the format of preceding part that I should have is (whitespaces are also important):                                                                                                    
line 7, hit #1: .....

Comment: you mean `'line {}, hit #{}: {}'.format(line_count, keyword_count, l.rstrip())`? what's the "mistake" it prints out exactly

Comment: @DariObukhova Can you specify desired output  and output that you are getting now in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to run your `script` on my Ubuntu machine with `Python 3.6.7`.

> When I try to insert ',' and '#' using {::=} and format, it prints out a mistake.

I fixed the indentation and your `format` String. I have removed first and third arguments from your `format` String. I think you want to print `line` String and `hit` String always in the same manner and then they shouldn't be in `format` arguments. I have also added `,` and `#` symbols to print the hits in your desired format.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

if len(sys.argv) <= 2:
    print("Error", file=sys.stderr)

filename = sys.argv[1]
keyword = sys.argv[2]

line_count = 0
keyword_count = 0
with open(filename, "r") as f:
     for l in f.readlines():
        line_count += 1
        if keyword in l:
            keyword_count += 1
            print ('line {0}, hit #{1}: {2}'.format(line_count, keyword_count, l.rstrip()))
```

I tested your script after modifications with a file having `print` keywords. The output of the script is below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Print Statement use like below

```
print ('{} {}, {} #{}, {}'.format('line', line_count, 'hit', 
         keyword_count, l.rstrip()))
```

It will print like below

> line 0, hit #0, `l`

l as in the string here